# JQuery debugging: how do I inspect the attached functions?

Tags: jquery

JQuery is a very powerful tool but it's hard to debug.

Have a look to the following image:
[image]

How can I easily find the piece of *.js file which contains the JQuery code which has been attached to this part of HTML code?

I think it's almost impossible since it could be attached through any of the CSS styles, id or other methods too.

**Looking to the attached event seem to not work correctly for JQuery attached events.**

How do you debug JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want but when you inspect element, on right side panel there is an event listener tab. If that's not what you want, then other options is [Monitor events](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#monitoring-events)

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work too well for jQuery event handlers because all the event handlers point to jQuery's generic event handler.

Comment: Yet possible to use monitor events in chrome dev tools. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#monitoring-events

Comment: And, how does that show the OP what jQuery code is linked to a specific object's event handler?

Comment: @SSA: I got this error: monitorEvents() => undefined

Comment: monitorevent needs the selector and event as parameter but as now I  understand your question, monitor event will not help either. I did some search and found this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-debugger/dbhhnnnpaeobfddmlalhnehgclcmjimi/related , which adds some extra options in chrome dev tools. You need to expand the right side panel as shown in image I posted, with extension you will get 3 extra tabs, may be that will help.

Answer (score 0):

You see on you screenshot : the list of Events bind to your element. Then you have a link to the Javascript file of each event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $._data.

Note, this is an internal-use only method!!!! << Important

```
// Bind up a couple of event handlers
​$("#foo").on({
    click: function(){ alert("MY evfent is here") }
});​​​

// Lookup events for this particular Element
​$._data( $("#foo")[0], "events" );
```

The result from $._data will be an object that contains events we set.